# Hide Axis Labels Blazor Bootstrap LineChart

Tags: html, blazor, blazor-bootstrap

I am using Blazor Bootstrap to create line charts to visualize data on a Blazor web page and would like to remove or hide the X-axis data labels. [image: Default Graph]

Currently, the chart is enclosed in a div to hide the labels at the bottom of the chart, however, this clips the bottom of the tooltip.[image: Clipped tooltip]

```
<div style="width:515px;height:250px;margin:auto;text-align:center;overflow:hidden;" class="child">
    <LineChart @ref="telemetryLineChart" Width="500"></LineChart>
</div>
```

Is there any way to hide the labels on the X-axis or align the tooltip to the top of the chart so it is not clipped?

Alternatively, reducing the number of displayed labels would also be a solution. Ie. instead of showing labels for every 40s, show for every 2 minutes without reducing the number of data points.

I'm just trying to get the graph to look nice. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you manage to find a better solution? I have the same issue

Comment: @Swifty not with Blazor bootstrap. Look into the Blazor wrapper for Apex Charts. Much more control over graphing options than bootstrap. https://apexcharts.github.io/Blazor-ApexCharts/